# How is spark's scala code exposed as a Java API?

Tags: java, scala, api, apache-spark

As I know Apache Spark is written in Scala. But its functionality is also exposed as a Java API[1], which in turn can be used in Java programs.

How is this done? Can someone explain me using an example.

In other words if I write a Scala program, and I want to expose it as a java API, what steps should be taken?

[1]http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/faq/4.html#4n263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will surely depend on the type of api you are exposing, but in general

- Simple methods can be called as is: `class A { def doSomething(s: String) }` in class A can be called just like a regular java method `new A().doSomehing("hello");`
- Default parameters in methods will not work. You will always have to call the method with the whole parameter list.
- traits with behaviour can't be implemented, but if you have common combinations you could create an abstract class and then you can extend that in java. Not sure if this will be solved with default methods for java8 in scala2.12
- For object functions you need to call using the escaped path. e.g. `object Container { val answer = 42 }` you get the constant value from java like `int answer = Container$.MODULE$.answer;`.

As I said first, it mostly depends on the api you want to expose from scala to java. If you have more specific cases I can edit them in this answer.